# populating json value into markup

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom-manipulation

I can't seem to be able to insert a JSON value into an input element in my markup.  Any ides?  I did verify that the .ajax call is returning the correct JSON. Its probably something simple, but I just can't seem to get it to work.  Thanks!

html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Index</title>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <form>
            <fieldset>
                <legend>The Person</legend>
                    <label>Name: </label>
                    <input id="Name"/>
                    <label>Age: </label>
                    <input id="Age" />

            </fieldset>

        </form>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/Custom.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

javascript

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/Home/GetPerson',
        type: 'GET',
        success: function (result) {
            alert(JSON.stringify(result));
            $('#Name').val(result[0].FirstName);
        }
    });
});
```

JSON.stringify returns

```
{"FirstName": "Steve", "LastName": "Smith"}
```

Comment: its a type of object.  The JSON is {"FirstName": "Steve", "LastName": "Smith"}

Comment: Have you tried `$('#Name').val(result.FirstName);`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> *The JSON is `{"FirstName": "Steve", "LastName": "Smith"}`*

Remove the `[0]` from `result[0].FirstName`:

```
$('#Name').val(result.FirstName);
```

The `[0]` part would only be applicable if `result` was an array of objects and you wanted the first item, e.g., if your JSON was something like this:

```
[{"FirstName": "Steve", "LastName": "Smith"}, {"FirstName": "Mary", "LastName": "Jones"}]
```

Comment: You sir deserve my +1 because you really try to educate here!

Comment: @RienNeVaPlus Yes, his goal is always this.

Comment: Thanks @RienNeVaPlus and undefined. And Lance, you're welcome.